# jQuery Validate plugin custom method not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
<script> 
    $("#form").validate();
    $(document).ready(function ()  
    {
        var merror = '';    
        jQuery.validator.addMethod('mvalid', function(value, element) {  
        if($("#mobile").hasClass("required") == true && ($("#mobile").val().substr(0,1) != '7' ||$("#mobile").val().substr(0,1) != '8' ||
        $("#mobile").val().substr(0,1) != '9'))  {                                        
            merror = 'Enter correct Mobile No.';
            return false;                                                     
        }
            return true;        
        }, merror); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: why is $("#mobile").val(); in quotes...?

Comment: remove quotes from var merror = '$("#mobile").val()';

Comment: It would have been more helpful for you to have explained that the "custom method" you're talking about is for the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please explain in detail, exactly what "not working" means.  Also, edit your OP to include the relevant HTML markup.

Comment: And again, where is the relevant HTML?

Comment: @Sparky , Sir , but this should need only jQuery Validation Code.Code to do validate Should be sufficient like op has given.

Comment: @PratikJoshi, Sir, please familiarize yourself with this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  ~  Not only does it help us understand where the OP is going wrong, it makes it easier to supply a working demo with the answer.

Comment: <form  id="form" >
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="mvalid" value="" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

Comment: @pratik still error msg  not showing on browser

Comment: What kind of error message ? I mean for digits between 0-9?

Comment: What does being new here have to do with writing out what you want?  Do you understand the core concept?  You are expected to **explain** to us, with **detail and specificity**, _what you're trying to do and how it's failing_.  Simply dumping chunks of code and expecting us to know what you want is unacceptable.  **Start by reading this please**:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The title contains the only shred of explanation, _"custom method not working"_, which is a duplicate.  If you have something more specific to ask, please post a new question, but first, **please take the time to follow these guidelines**:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a custom method to simply show a custom message for the `required`  rule.  Just use the `messages` option.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        mobile: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        mobile: {
            required: 'Enter Mobile No.'
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/dLq5t/**

---

**EDIT**:

Otherwise, if you need a custom rule, the message is the last item within.   It will display when the element fails validation.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('mvalid', function(value, element, params) {
     // your custom function
     // return true to pass validation
     // return false to fail validation and display error message
}, 'Enter Mobile No.');
```

See documentation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

BTW:  You do not need to check for an empty field within your custom function because the `required` rule already takes care of that.  And you don't need to check for a `required` `class`, again, because the plugin already does that by default.

Comment: Then use custom method ,and use it as => customMobileValidatin: true below required:true

Comment: @user3682603, see my edit for where to place your custom message within the custom method.

Comment: @Sparky , He wants ready-made method for His logic

Comment: @PratikJoshi, if he can make a more specific question, then he'll get a more specific answer.  As you can see, the "title" is the only place where he's actually said anything.  It's not our job to piece this all together based on comments and mind-reading.